# test a repository in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following method in my repository and I want to test it

```
public function myFindOne($id)
{
// On passe par le QueryBuilder vide de l'EntityManager pour l'exemple
  $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

  $qb->select('a')
     ->from('xxxBundle:entity', 'a')
     ->where('a.id = :id')
     ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();}
```

I found the following code in the documentation, but I could not understand it

```
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Tests/Entity/ProductRepositoryFunctionalTest.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Tests\Entity;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ProductRepositoryFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
        static::$kernel->boot();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
        ;
    }

    public function testSearchByCategoryName()
    {
        $products = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
            ->searchByCategoryName('foo')
        ;

        $this->assertCount(1, $products);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        $this->em->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, if you need an one element by the id or any other field, you can simply use `$this->getDoctrine()      ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->findOneById($id)`. (you can replace `findOneById` by `findOneByName` or whatever field name you want to use.)

Comment: and what about tearDown and so on?? @cheesemacfly

Comment: an other question also is how to execute it? @cheesemacfly

Comment: good comment by @cheesemacfly. Waiting for responses - upvoted though "i could not understand it" is a really bad question...

Comment: What you can't understand?

Comment: @RenanIvo what should I modify in this code to make it compatible with my repository?

Answer (score 0):

To see what you should edit in this code, the `testSearchByCatergory()` should be a good start. In this example, it gets the result of the tested method into `$products` and checks that this collection contains only one element.

So I guess your test would be to test that the returned object is the one you expect to be returned. But heh, like @cheesemacfly said, your repo is kinda the same as `findOne[ById]()`... Oh and BTW, you should check up [phpunit [EN]](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/index.html) ([Or in FR](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/fr/index.html), as I saw in your comment)  documentation to see how you should make it run.

Cheers. :)

Comment: I get the following error : Runtime exception : unable to guess the kernel directory

Answer (score 0):

From [Symfony's official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html), the Repository methods should be tested as follow:

```
// tests/AppBundle/Entity/ProductRepositoryTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class ProductRepositoryTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function testSearchByCategoryName()
    {
        $products = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
            ->searchByCategoryName('foo')
        ;

        $this->assertCount(1, $products);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->em->close();
    }
}
```